# DateTime string format in c#

Tags: c#, string, variables, datetime, converters

I have a project that contain 3 string variables.

1. `DateFormatStr` is the format string I need to use to output dates.
2. `DateFormatFrom` is the start date a request will apply from
3. `FilloutDateTo` is the end date the request will apply to.

The problem is that I don't want to manually specify the dates. As you can see in my example below (a working example), I need to specify the dates, but is there a way to make it that the from date has time 00:00:00 and the end date has time 23:59:59?

```
string DateFormatStr = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt";
string DateFormatFrom = "12/04/14 00:00:00";
string FilloutDateTo = "12/04/14 23:59:59";
```

So I would like to the system time to recognize the from date and the start date respecting the `formatStr` variable.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried to make your question clearer. Let me know if I have misunderstood what you meant to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use [`DateTime.Today` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) like;

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Today;
var dt2 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

and use [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ToString(v=vs.110).aspx) to format them like;

```
var DateFormatFrom = dt1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var FilloutDateTo = dt2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Results will be;

```
12/04/2014 00:00:00
12/04/2014 23:59:59
```

You used [`hh` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hhSpecifier) but it is for 12-hour clock. Use [`HH` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#HH_Specifier) instead which is for 24-hour clock. And since your result strings doesn't have any AM/PM designator, you don't need to use `tt` format specifier.

Comment: It worked, this is amazing!!!!!!! You have saved me so much time!!!! I been searching on the net all over and nothing!! thanks a lot!!!! really thanks you!!!!

Comment: @BenjaminArancibia Glad to help. You are quite welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In `C# 6.0` you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/csharp-six#String-Interpolation) in order to display formatted dates.

```
DateTime startOfDay = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endOfDay = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);

string dateFormatFrom = $"{startOfDay: MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt}";
string filloutDateTo =  $"{endOfDay: MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt}";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string idate = "01/11/2019 19:00:00";
DateTime odate = Convert.ToDateTime(idate);
DateTime sdate1 = DateTime.Parse(idate);
string outDate1 = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", sdate1.Day, sdate1.Month,sdate1.Year);
Console.WriteLine(outDate1);
```