# To pass specific Date format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How we can pass specific Date format like "MM/dd/YYYY" in place of System.DateTime in below code.

```
new ObjectParameter("FromDate", typeof(System.DateTime));
```

Comment: You don't. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Use `DateTime.ToString()`?

Comment: `MM/dd/YYYY` is just fancy way to represent a human readable date string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime string format in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303110/datetime-string-format-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but i guess you are looking for a way to convert the `DateTime` to `string` in this format. Then you can use `DateTime.ToString` with an appropriate format string:

```
string result = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

I'm using `InvariantInfo` to force the `/` as separator. Otherwise it would be replaced with your localized date separator. See: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator).

Another way to force `/` as date separator is to escape the `/` format specifier with `'`:

```
string result = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can't*.

A `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. Format concept *only* applies when you get it's *textual* (string) representation.

There is only [two constructor of that `ObjectParameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectparameter.objectparameter) which one is expect `Object` and the other one expect `Type` as a second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how you want the DateTime formatted when using .ToString(), by entering a parameter in the ToString() method, like so: `somedatetime.ToString("d");`

You can read more about the formatting here: [DateTime.ToString Method at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)